# How do I SELECT with Couchbase, N1QL and PHP?

Tags: php, select, couchbase, sql++

I am trying to do a SELECT with Couchbase, N1QL and PHP. This will get the whole row. I need to get a certain field, for example country. How do I do that? This is my current script.

```
// Set bucket
$bucketName = "travel-sample";

// Connect to Couchbase Server
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster("couchbase://127.0.0.1");
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket($bucketName);

// Get data
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT * FROM `travel-sample` LIMIT 4');
$result = $bucket->query($query);
foreach ($result->rows as $row) {
    $json = json_encode($row);
    echo $json;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL statement so that it returns only the desired field(s).  Using the "*", you are asking you DB for all the fields in table travel-sample.

Changing your query line to

```
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT country FROM `travel-sample` LIMIT 4');
```

or (multiple fields)

```
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT country, other_field FROM `travel-sample` LIMIT 4');
```

Should work for you.